# The magnitude of the complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

How can we find $|M|^2$ for $$M=\frac{e^{2(1+{\rm i})l}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})l}}{e^{2(1+{\rm i})x}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})x}} ?$$

We have $$M=\frac{\cos 2l[e^{2l}-e^{-2l}]+{\rm i} \sin 2l[e^{2l}+e^{-2l}]}{\cos 2x[e^{2x}-e^{-2x}]+{\rm i} \sin 2x[e^{2x}+e^{-2x}]} = \frac{2\sinh 2l \cos 2l+2{\rm i} \sin 2l \cosh 2l}{2 \sinh 2x\cos 2x+2{\rm i} \cosh 2x \sin 2x} .$$

Then we multiply the upper and lower terms with $2 \sinh 2x\cos 2x-2{\rm i} \cosh 2x \sin 2x$ and obtain $$\frac{[2 \cos(2 x) \sinh(2 x)  - 2 {\rm i} \cosh(2 x) \sin(2 x) ] [ \cos(2 l) \sinh(2 l) 2 + \cosh(2 l) \sin(2 l) 2 i]}{4 \sinh^2(2x) \cos^2(2x)+4 \cosh^2(2x) \sin^2(2x)} .$$ So what I can do after that? How can I find $|M|^2$?

Comment: @MJD it is correct that $|\frac{a}{b}|=\frac{|a|}{|b|}$, but in my question is different because it is complex function.

Answer (score 2):

It's convenient to calculate for a quantity $M=\frac{a}{b}$ the square of the absolute value $|M|^2$ according to the formula

\begin{align*}
|M|^2=M\overline{M}=\frac{a}{b}\overline{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}=\frac{a\overline{a}}{b\overline{b}}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> |M|^2&=M\overline{M}\\
> &=\frac{e^{2(1+{\rm i})l}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})l}}{e^{2(1+{\rm i})x}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})x}}
> \cdot\overline{\left(\frac{e^{2(1+{\rm i})l}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})l}}{e^{2(1+{\rm i})x}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})x}}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{e^{2(1+{\rm i})l}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})l}}{e^{2(1+{\rm i})x}-e^{-2(1+{\rm i})x}}
> \cdot\frac{e^{2(1-{\rm i})l}-e^{-2(1-{\rm i})l}}{e^{2(1-{\rm i})x}-e^{-2(1-{\rm i})x}}\\
> &=\frac{e^{4l}-e^{-4{\rm i}l}-e^{4{\rm i}l}+e^{-4l}}{e^{4x}-e^{-4{\rm i}x}-e^{4{\rm i}x}+e^{-4x}}\\
> &=\frac{\left(e^{4l}+e^{-4l}\right)-\left(e^{4{\rm i}l}+e^{-4{\rm i}l}\right)}{\left(e^{4x}+e^{-4x}\right)-\left(e^{4{\rm i}x}+e^{-4{\rm i}x}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{\cosh(4l)-\cos(4l)}{\cosh(4x)-\cos(4x)}
> \end{align*}